# Populate textbox from <select> using Knockout

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Hi I wonder if you could help. This problem has been bugging me. I am trying to populate a textbox based on a selected value on `<select>`. The `<select>` is populated from MVC backend `self.ApplicationsList = ko.observableArray(data.ApplicationsList);` `ApplicationsList` is just `List<Application>` Below is my implementation. A table is populated with rows of roles. When a row is clicked, the `<input>` and `<select>` are populated with the correct values. So far so good. I would like this to extend further, ie, when I select a different option on `<select>`, `<input id="ApplicationDescription>"` should be populated with the description values based on `self.ApplicationsList` observable. I just can't get my head round this.

MVC class

```
public class Application
{
    public int AppID { get; set; }
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    public string AppDesc { get; set; }
}
```

Knockout ViewModel

```
var RoleVM = function (data) {
var self = this;

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

self.Roles = ko.observableArray(data.RolesList);
self.ApplicationsList = ko.observableArray(data.ApplicationsList);

self.RoleID = ko.observable();
self.RoleName = ko.observable();
self.Description = ko.observable();
self.ApplicationName = ko.observable();
self.ApplicationDescription = ko.observable();
self.ApplicationID = ko.observable();

self.GetSelectedRole = function (role) {
    self.RoleID(role.RoleID);
    self.RoleName(role.RoleName);
    self.Description(role.Description);
    self.ApplicationName(role.ApplicationName);
    self.ApplicationDescription(role.ApplicationDescription);
    self.ApplicationID(role.ApplicationID);
};

//New addition
self.SelectedApplication = ko.observable("");
self.ApplicationID.subscribe(function (value) {
    self.SelectedApplication(value);
});
```

};

View

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>RoleID</th>
        <th>RoleName</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>ApplicationName</th>
        <th>ApplicationDescription</th>
        <th data-bind="visible: false"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody data-bind="foreach: Roles">
    <tr data-bind="click: $root.GetSelectedRole" id="updtr">
        <td><span data-bind="text: RoleID"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: RoleName"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Description"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: ApplicationName"></span></td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: ApplicationDescription"></span></td>
        <td data-bind="visible: false"><span data-bind="text: ApplicationID"></span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<table data-bind="visible: ReadOnlyMode">
<tr>
    <td><label for="RoleID">Role ID:</label></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: RoleID" type="text" id="RoleID" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="RoleName">Role Name:</label></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: RoleName" type="text" id="RoleName" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="Description">Role Description:</label></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: Description" type="text" id="Description" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="ApplicationName">Application:</label></td>
    <td><select data-bind="options: ApplicationsList, optionsText: 'AppName', optionsValue: 'AppID', value: ApplicationID"></select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="ApplicationDescription">Application Description:</label></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: SelectedApplication" type="text" id="ApplicationDescription" /></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a subscription on your ApplicationID.

This will fire when the ApplicationID observable changes, and you can update other observables and do whatever else you need.

Ex:

```
self.ApplicationID.subscribe(function (val) {

    //Do what you need here to update other observables...

});
```

Comment: Thanks. What is passed in as `val`? How do I call ApplicationID observable from the view?

Comment: I have edited my original code block to include subscription logic to ApplicationID. It passes `value` to `SelectedApplication` observable and I data bind `input id="ApplicationDescription"` to `SelectedApplication`. When I make a selection on `<select>`, it puts the value of `<option>` in the `input`. I'm moving in the right direction but how can I associate the `option` value to the `self.ApplicationsList.AppDesc` property so that it loads the description of the selected application?

Comment: Is this recommended? `self.SelectedApplication(self.ApplicationsList()[value-1].AppDesc);`